# Custom javascript appending info to URL modification

Tags: javascript, html

We build pages on old outdated local school network and the JavaScript below is automatically added to all pages. *No one is sure where the script is and how appended to pages and the person who set it all up is long gone*. Until things are updated (who know when - suppose to be this coming summer), need some advice.

What I am attempting to do is modify script so some links are not affected. In other words standard < a href > links use the script but chosen/tadded ones do not.

Looking for way to flag certain links to prevent the script from modifying.

```js
  var links = document.links;
  var thisHost = location.host;
  var i = links.length;

  while (i--) {

   if (links[i].href.slice(-1) == "#" || links[i].getAttribute("href").slice(0, 3) == "../") {
    continue;
   }

   links[i].href = "local://" + (links[i].href);

  }
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

Any input appreciated. I have exhausted all attempts at solution...

Comment: Use google chrome to inspect and find it?

Comment: @shadow-codex not quite that simple on a locked down school network server. wish it was that simple:)

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the problem, but can you add a "class" value to the links you don't want to modify, and use a CSS selector to find a href links that don't have that class? Or alternative, add a "class" value to the links you DO want to modify, and use a css selector to find a hrefs that do have the class?

Comment: Add a `#` to the end of the links that you want it to skip.

Comment: So, you cannot modify this particular script, but you can add another script, correct? Also, you can modify the markup of those links you want to tag, right?

Comment: @shef Correct, cannot modify existing script but can add new ones to page(s).

Comment: @paulpro Yes, that does work! But like to get rid of the # if at all possible. Good catch nevertheless, thanks.

Comment: @Woody If you find the script you can do something along the line of Alan's suggestion. It shouldn't be too hard to find, look at the web server config to see where the request is routed to and read that code to see how the script gets inserted (or maybe it's inserted directly by the web server). Or just `grep 'document\.links' -R *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That script skips over links that end in `#`, so if the link doesn't have a `#` already you can add one to the end of it. If you find the script you could also modify it to skip links that have a certain class, EG.

```
if (links[i].className.match('\bskip-modify\b') || links[i].href.slice(-1) == "#" || ...
```

It shouldn't be too hard to find. Look at the web server config to see where the request is routed to and read that code to see how the script gets inserted (or maybe it's inserted directly by the web server). Or just `grep 'document\.links' -R *`.

Otherwise you can add a script that runs after the DOM is ready (in case that the other script is inserted below yours) and undoes what that script does for links with the class "skip-modify":

```
!function ( ) {

    if ( document.addEventListener ) {
       document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", undoLinkModifications );
    } else {
      document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){
        if (document.readyState === "complete"){
          document.detachEvent( "onreadystatechange", arguments.callee );
          undoLinkModifications( );
        }
      });
    }

    function undoLinkModifications ( ) {
        var els = document.querySelectorAll( '.skip-modify' );
        for ( var i = 0; i < els.length; i++ ) {
            els[i].href = els[i].href.replace( /^local:\/\//, '' );
        }
    }

}();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o34ushx5/)

Comment: Perfect! Does just what we need with ease. So many good answers here but your does it best. Thanks to you and everyone else who provided great input.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `class` attribute to the anchor tag, and in your new script code use CSS selectors to find those links and modify them.

You'll need to determine when to execute the javascript, onLoad, or onDocumentReady, but this should work for you.

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://tempuri.org">Static URI</a><br>
<a class="update" href="http://tempuri.org">URI To Update</a><hr>
<input type="button" onclick="runme()" value="update links">
```

**Javascript**

```
function runme() {
 var elements = document.querySelectorAll('a.update');
 elements.forEach( function(element) {
  element.setAttribute('href','http://www.google.com');
  element.innerHTML = 'Updated to Google.com';
 });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ued2a29y/3/

Answer (score 1):

The auto-appended script you have, bypasses links that end with the `#`. Using that knowledge, you can tackle the tagging & updating as follows.

#### 1. HTML Markup

For all anchors you don't want URLs changed to local, set the href attribute to `#`, tag with a class `nonlocal`, and set the real URL you want them to have in a data attribute.

```
<a href="#" class="nonlocal" data-href="http://www.REAL-URL-GOES-HERE.com">Nonlocal Anchor</a>
```

#### 2. JavaScript

Append the following JavaScript at the end of the page and it should handle all the substitutions of `#` with the real URLs.

```
(function() {
    // get all tagged links
    var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a.nonlocal');

    // set their real URL
    anchors.forEach(function(anchor) {
        anchor.setAttribute('href', anchor.datasets.href);
    });
})();
```

#### 3. Enjoy!